# User update hook

Tags: hooks, users

I am using `profile_update`hook for user update but it is working only for my own profile. I need hook which works for all users including my own profile.
Which hook I should use for this purpose ?
Here how I am using this in my theme's functions.php.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    if(is_admin()){

    }
}
```

Comment: This action fires for all users. How are you using this hook (code example)?

Comment: @czerspalace I added code example in my question. Should I increase priority ?

Comment: How do you know this doesn't work

Comment: I tested this by adding redirect and also I added exit in this function. Profile.php redirects and also execute exit statement but both these are not working for user-edit.php.

Comment: I would need more information about what you are doing and what you are expecting, and what are you doing in the website when this works and what you are doing when it doesnt work.

Comment: Upon user update or own profile update I am fetching user data and passing data via API. This is what I am doing. profile_update hook works for my own profile but not for other users.

Comment: @wplearner Posting "example" code is not helpful. It's your real code that's not working. Please share the actual code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @czerspalace there were two conditions which were stopping user-edit.php page in above code. I also have increased priority and it is working for me now. Please add your answer and I will accept that. Thank you!